# Serviço Android roda somente na primeira vez

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde é feito sincronização com um web services. O aplicativo é muito simples, faz uma relação de perguntas, o usuário responde, ao clicar em finalizar, grava esses dados no banco de dados do celular, e faz a replicação, pois pode estar ou não conectado a internet.

O meu problema é seguinte, toda primeira vez que abro o sistema e faço todo o processo, tudo funciona perfeitamente, sincroniza, lança a notificação pro celular, faz tudo certo e volta para a tela para começar um novo processo.

Na segunda vez que é feito, é gravado no banco de dados do celular, mas não sincroniza, parece que o serviço simplesmente nao é executado.

Quando eu fecho o sistema, limpo ele da memória, aí é feita a sincronização. Já fiz vários teste e até agora não consegui resolver.

Segue os códigos:

```java
public void finalizaCheckList(){
    ContentValues ctvResposta = new ContentValues();
    ctvResposta.put("status",1);
    SQLiteDatabase dbResposta = openOrCreateDatabase("respostas.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    long iCodigoResposta = dbResposta.insert("respostas","_id",ctvResposta);
    dbResposta.close();


    for (int i = 0; i < alR.size(); i++){
        RadioGroup rgResposta = alR.get(i);
        int handleItemSelecionado = rgResposta.getId();
        int itenSelecionado =   rgResposta.indexOfChild(findViewById(rgResposta.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

        ContentValues ctv = new ContentValues();
        ctv.put("placa",placa);
        ctv.put("placanumero",_placanumero);
        ctv.put("handle_checklist",handle_checklist);
        ctv.put("tipopergunta",1);
        ctv.put("handle_checklist_pergunta",handleItemSelecionado);
        if (itenSelecionado == 0){
            ctv.put("resposta","S");
        } else {
            ctv.put("resposta","N");
        }
        ctv.put("usuario",handle_usuario);
        ctv.put("sincronizado",1);
        ctv.put("codigo_resposta",iCodigoResposta);

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db1.insert("checklist_resposta","_id",ctv);
        db1.close();
    }


    for (int ii = 0; ii < alE.size(); ii++){
        EditText edResposta = alE.get(ii);

        int handleItemSelecionado = edResposta.getId();
        String resposta = edResposta.getText().toString();

        ContentValues ctv = new ContentValues();
        ctv.put("placa",placa);
        ctv.put("placanumero",_placanumero);
        ctv.put("handle_checklist",handle_checklist);
        ctv.put("tipopergunta",2);
        ctv.put("handle_checklist_pergunta",handleItemSelecionado);
        ctv.put("resposta",resposta);
        ctv.put("usuario",handle_usuario);
        ctv.put("sincronizado",1);
        ctv.put("codigo_resposta",iCodigoResposta);

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db1.insert("checklist_resposta","_id",ctv);
        db1.close();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent("br.cooper.system.checklist.ReplicarCheckLists") ;
    this.startService(intent) ;
}
```

Arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<service android:name="br.cooper.system.checklist.ReplicarCheckLists"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="br.cooper.system.checklist.ReplicarCheckLists"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Meu código de replicação:

```java
public class ReplicarCheckLists extends Service implements Runnable {
private Handler mainHandler;
private Handler handler;
private String sXML = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    if (verificaConexao()){
        new Thread(ReplicarCheckLists.this).start();
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    handler = new Handler();

    boolean post = handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Criado para ser gerado quando for disparado a Thread
            SQLiteDatabase sqlRespostas = openOrCreateDatabase("respostas.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursorResposta = sqlRespostas.rawQuery("select _id from respostas where status = 1",null);

            SQLiteDatabase sqlSincronizado = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursorR = sqlSincronizado.rawQuery("select placanumero from checklist_resposta group by placanumero", null);

            try {
                SQLiteDatabase sql = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor cursor = null;
                Cursor cursorAtualizacao = sql.rawQuery("select _id, handle_checklist, placa, handle_checklist_pergunta, tipopergunta, usuario, resposta, placanumero, handle_checklist  from checklist_resposta where sincronizado = 1", null);

                SincronizaRespostas sincrona = new SincronizaRespostas();
                String sResposta = "";

                boolean bCabacalho = false;
                while (cursorResposta.moveToNext()){
                    cursor = sql.rawQuery("select _id, handle_checklist, placa, handle_checklist_pergunta, tipopergunta, usuario, resposta, placanumero, handle_checklist  " +
                            "from checklist_resposta where sincronizado = 1 " +
                            "and codigo_resposta =  " + cursorResposta.getString(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")) , null);
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        if (!bCabacalho) {
                            geraXML("respostachecklist", "", false);
                            geraXML("placa", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("placa")), false);
                            geraXML("checklist", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist")), false);
                            geraXML("usuario", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("usuario")), false);

                            bCabacalho = true;
                        }

                        geraXML("respostas","",false);
                        geraXML("pergunta", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist_pergunta")), false);
                        geraXML("tipopergunta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipopergunta")),false);
                        geraXML("resposta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resposta")),false);
                        geraXML("respostas", "", true);
                    }
                    geraXML("respostachecklist","",true);



                    if (sincrona.sincoriza(sXML).equals("OK")) {
                        gravaItemOk(cursorResposta.getInt(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                }

                sqlSincronizado.close();
                cursor.close();
                cursorAtualizacao.close();
                cursorR.close();
                sql.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                notificacao(cursorR.getString(cursorR.getColumnIndex("placanumero")), true);
                Log.d("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", ex.getMessage());
            }


        }
    });
    Looper.loop();
    stopSelf();


}
```

Não sei se consegui me fazer entender, mas o problema parece ser simples, mas a solução ainda não achei. Não sei se alguém já passou por isso!!

---

## Atualização

Fiz um teste usando o `AsyncTask`. O código ficou assim:

```java
public class ReplicarCheckLists extends Service {
private Handler mainHandler;
private Handler handler;
private String sXML = "";


@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    // Migra a lógica de sincronização para o handleCommand
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    handleCommand();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void handleCommand() {
    // Inicia uma nova AsyncTask para realizar as operações fora da Main Thread
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Criado para ser gerado quando for disparado a Thread
            SQLiteDatabase sqlRespostas = openOrCreateDatabase("respostas.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursorResposta = sqlRespostas.rawQuery("select _id, placa from respostas where status = 1",null);

            String sPlacaNumero = "";

            try {
                SQLiteDatabase sql = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor cursor = null;

                SincronizaRespostas sincrona = new SincronizaRespostas();


                boolean bCabacalho = false;
                while (cursorResposta.moveToNext()){
                    sPlacaNumero = cursorResposta.getString(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("placa"));
                    cursor = sql.rawQuery("select _id, handle_checklist, placa, handle_checklist_pergunta, tipopergunta, usuario, resposta, placanumero, handle_checklist  " +
                            "from checklist_resposta where sincronizado = 1 " +
                            "and codigo_resposta =  " + cursorResposta.getString(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")) , null);


                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        if (!bCabacalho) {
                            geraXML("respostachecklist", "", false);
                            geraXML("placa", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("placa")), false);
                            geraXML("checklist", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist")), false);
                            geraXML("usuario", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("usuario")), false);

                            bCabacalho = true;
                        }

                        geraXML("respostas","",false);
                        geraXML("pergunta", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist_pergunta")), false);
                        geraXML("tipopergunta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipopergunta")),false);
                        geraXML("resposta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resposta")),false);
                        geraXML("respostas", "", true);
                    }

                    geraXML("respostachecklist","",true);

                    if (sincrona.sincoriza(sXML).equals("OK")) {
                        gravaItemOk(cursorResposta.getInt(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                        notificacao(sPlacaNumero, false);
                    } else {
                        notificacao(sPlacaNumero, true);
                    }

                }


                cursorResposta.close();
                sql.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Porém ocorre o seguinte erro:

> 22856-23026/br.cooper.system.checklist:remote D/DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD﹕ println needs a message

Não sei o que pode ser, pq esse erro é de um `try-catch`.

E continua sincronizando apos fechar o aplicativo por total.

Mais alguma coisa que eu possa estar fazendo para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Sim, esta correto o comportamento. Vou verificar um ponto que ainda não tenho certeza e preparo uma resposta.

Comment: Troque o `Log.d` por um `e.printStackTrace` para ver mais detalhes sobre o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de tanto forçar uma tentativa de sucesso, acho que descobri o que pode ser, na verdade uma alternativa que nao sei se é a mais indicada, mas aparentemente funcionou, simplesmente forcei a parada do serviço:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("br.cooper.system.checklist.ReplicarCheckLists") ;
    stopService(intent) ;
```

Caso tenha algum problema que alguém já tenha passado usando dessa maneira!??!

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Fiquei pensando qual poderia ser o erro e pela forma como foi feito, apesar de não se recomendada, funciona (na teoria).

Olhando seu código, ele deveria recriar o `Service` (chamando `onCreate`) toda vez que chamasse `startService`, não faço idéia do porque exatamente. Minha hipótese é que ele deve estar reutilizando a mesma instância e por isso não chama o `onCreate` mesmo chamando `stopSelf()`.

Se me permite, sugiro um *refactoring* no seu código.

Em vez de usar o `onCreate` para fazer sua lógica de sincronização, use o `onStartCommand` (é recomendado nas versões superior a SDK 5) para fazer sua lógica.

Além disso, como esta usando `Threads`, já chegou a olhar [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? É uma camada que facilita a manipulação de `Threads` e atualização da UI. Sei que não tem UI envolvida, mas fica a dica.

Outra modificação seria parar de implementar a interface `Runnable` e usando  uma `AsyncTask` [anônima](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), mesmo que não tenha UI, para facilitar o código.

Ficaria algo como:

```
public class ReplicarCheckLists extends Service {
    private Handler mainHandler;
    private Handler handler;
    private String sXML = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        // Migra a lógica de sincronização para o handleCommand
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        handleCommand();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handleCommand();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void handleCommand() {
        // Inicia uma nova AsyncTask para realizar as operações fora da Main Thread

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //Criado para ser gerado quando for disparado a Thread
                SQLiteDatabase sqlRespostas = openOrCreateDatabase("respostas.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor cursorResposta = sqlRespostas.rawQuery("select _id from respostas where status = 1",null);

                SQLiteDatabase sqlSincronizado = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor cursorR = sqlSincronizado.rawQuery("select placanumero from checklist_resposta group by placanumero", null);

                try {
                    SQLiteDatabase sql = openOrCreateDatabase("checklist_resposta.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    Cursor cursorAtualizacao = sql.rawQuery("select _id, handle_checklist, placa, handle_checklist_pergunta, tipopergunta, usuario, resposta, placanumero, handle_checklist  from checklist_resposta where sincronizado = 1", null);

                    SincronizaRespostas sincrona = new SincronizaRespostas();
                    String sResposta = "";

                    boolean bCabacalho = false;
                    while (cursorResposta.moveToNext()){
                        cursor = sql.rawQuery("select _id, handle_checklist, placa, handle_checklist_pergunta, tipopergunta, usuario, resposta, placanumero, handle_checklist  " +
                                              "from checklist_resposta where sincronizado = 1 " +
                                              "and codigo_resposta =  " + cursorResposta.getString(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")) , null);

                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            if (!bCabacalho) {
                                geraXML("respostachecklist", "", false);
                                geraXML("placa", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("placa")), false);
                                geraXML("checklist", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist")), false);
                                geraXML("usuario", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("usuario")), false);

                                bCabacalho = true;
                            }

                            geraXML("respostas","",false);
                            geraXML("pergunta", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle_checklist_pergunta")), false);
                            geraXML("tipopergunta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipopergunta")),false);
                            geraXML("resposta",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resposta")),false);
                            geraXML("respostas", "", true);
                        }

                        geraXML("respostachecklist","",true);

                        if (sincrona.sincoriza(sXML).equals("OK")) {
                            gravaItemOk(cursorResposta.getInt(cursorResposta.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                        }

                        cursor.close();
                    }

                    sqlSincronizado.close();
                    cursor.close();
                    cursorAtualizacao.close();
                    cursorR.close();
                    sql.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    notificacao(cursorR.getString(cursorR.getColumnIndex("placanumero")), true);
                    Log.d("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wakim, 

Vou Fazer um teste hoje a noite e reporto se deu certo ou não.

Por hora muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Coloque essa implementação no seu serviço:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{


   // Este flag faz com que o sistema restart o serviço caso seja parado, tanto pelo
   //usuário como pelo sistema. Só o aplicativo poderá pará-lo
    return START_STICKY;

}
```